# Problems with Joining Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to join two tables one containing Dept codes another a pivot table but each time I try to join the table it throws me the following error:
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'D'. Is there a better way of doing this or have I overlooked an error. ?

I've tried various different joins but it all throws me the same error

```
SELECT D.Dept_Code, D.Department, S.Amount AS 'Total Amount' FROM DEPARTMENT AS D JOIN(
SELECT DEPT, (ISNULL([63121],0) +ISNULL([63122],0)+ ISNULL([63123],0)+ISNULL([63124],0)+ISNULL([63125],0)+ISNULL([63126],0)+ISNULL([63129],0)) AS 'Amount', (ISNULL([63131],0) + ISNULL([63139], 0)) AS '63130', ISNULL([63141], 0) AS '63141', ISNULL([63143],0) AS '63143', ISNULL([63144], 0) AS '63144', ISNULL([63145],0) AS '63145', ISNULL([63146],0) AS '63146', ISNULL([63149], 0) AS '632149'
FROM(SELECT DEPT, NATURE, SUM(CAST(Amount AS FLOAT)) AS AMOUNT FROM MFG_EXP_1 GROUP BY DEPT, NATURE) AS S
PIVOT
(
SUM(AMOUNT)
FOR NATURE IN ([63121], [63122], [63123], [63124], [63125], [63126], [63129], [63131], [63139], [63141], [63142], [63143], [63144], [63145], [63146], [63149])
) NATURE_CODE_BREAKDOWN) AS G ON D D.Dept = G.DEPT;
```

I try to join the table it throws me the following error:
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'D'

The Department table:

```
Dept_Code Dept     Department    
100        110       merchandsing
100        120       operations
```

the MFG_EXP 1 Table

``````````````````
Dept Nature Amount
110   1000   $200
120   2000   $300
`````````````````
When I Pivot the MFG_EXP_1 Table by the Nature codes I have the newly formed SourceTable Below:
`````````````````
Dept  1000    2000
110   $200.00  $0.00
120   $0.00    $300.00
``````````````````

I now want to join my SourceTable with my Department Table to have This as my final result

```
Dept Department  1000     2000
100  merchandise $200.00 $0.00
100  Operations  $0.00   $300.00
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question, select all the sql code and press the `{}` button above the edit box ?

Comment: I can see for sure that `AS G ON D D.Dept = G.DEPT;` is a syntax error-  you have too many letter D there

Comment: How would I need to modify it ? I changed it to an abrevated text but it throws me the same error

Comment: I'm kinda confused why you're bothering to pivot when all you seem to do is then add all the columns up to each other? That would b much easier done with a SUM(AMOUNT) WHERE NATURE IN (...) GROUP BY dept (leave it as one column of many rows and sum the one rather than pivoting to 20 columns and then having this laborios ifnull+ifnull+ifnull... 20 times

Comment: You actually be better off showing us the data you have and an example output for that data, then we'll do the query. This is an XY problem; you're coming for help with your broken solution when it might be better to hear the original problem and solve that (not fix your broken attempt at solving it) if that makes sense

Comment: Thats understandable. I am trying to recreate a pivot report where a group previously has been doing manually in excel using sql.

Answer (score 0):

I see a syntax problem at the end of your SQL statement:

```
D D.Dept = G.DEPT;
```

But in general if you use CTE and put your pivot table as CTE expression, you can simplify your SQL statement and easily test each separately.
Like this:

```
;USING myPivot AS (
-- just copied your statement here
SELECT DEPT, (ISNULL([63121],0) +ISNULL([63122],0)+ ISNULL([63123],0)+ISNULL([63124],0)+ISNULL([63125],0)+ISNULL([63126],0)+ISNULL([63129],0)) AS 'Amount', (ISNULL([63131],0) + ISNULL([63139], 0)) AS '63130', ISNULL([63141], 0) AS '63141', ISNULL([63143],0) AS '63143', ISNULL([63144], 0) AS '63144', ISNULL([63145],0) AS '63145', ISNULL([63146],0) AS '63146', ISNULL([63149], 0) AS '632149'
FROM(SELECT DEPT, NATURE, SUM(CAST(Amount AS FLOAT)) AS AMOUNT FROM MFG_EXP_1 GROUP BY DEPT, NATURE) AS S
PIVOT
(
SUM(AMOUNT)
FOR NATURE IN ([63121], [63122], [63123], [63124], [63125], [63126], [63129], [63131], [63139], [63141], [63142], [63143], [63144], [63145], [63146], [63149])
)
)

SELECT D.Dept_Code, D.Department, S.Amount AS 'Total Amount' FROM DEPARTMENT AS D 
   JOIN myPivot D ON D.Dept = G.DEPT
```

Comment: Thanks to you both but I am still seeing some syntax error's using both schemas when I run them

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stab at fixing your query but not having anything to test it against it might still have some problem:

```
SELECT
  D.Dept_Code, 
  D.Department, 
  S.Amount AS TotalAmount 
FROM 
  DEPARTMENT AS D 
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
      DEPT, 
      (ISNULL([63121],0) +ISNULL([63122],0)+ ISNULL([63123],0)+ISNULL([63124],0)+ISNULL([63125],0)+ISNULL([63126],0)+ISNULL([63129],0)) AS [Amount],   
      (ISNULL([63131],0) + ISNULL([63139], 0)) AS [63130], 
      ISNULL([63141], 0) AS [63141], 
      ISNULL([63143],0) AS [63143], 
      ISNULL([63144], 0) AS [63144], 
      ISNULL([63145],0) AS [63145], 
      ISNULL([63146],0) AS [63146], 
      ISNULL([63149], 0) AS [632149]
  FROM
    (
      SELECT DEPT, NATURE, SUM(CAST(Amount AS FLOAT)) AS AMOUNT 
      FROM MFG_EXP_1 
      GROUP BY DEPT, NATURE
    ) AS S
    PIVOT
    (
      SUM(AMOUNT)
      FOR NATURE IN ([63121], [63122], [63123], [63124], [63125], [63126], [63129], [63131], [63139], [63141], [63142], [63143], [63144], [63145], [63146], [63149])
    ) NATURE_CODE_BREAKDOWN
  ) AS G ON D.Dept = G.DEPT;
```